# What does this php statement mean?

Tags: php, function

I want to make some changes on a php file. What does this statement mean?:

```
if(($aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"] == '') || ($aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"] != $_POST['sepabanktransfer_swift']))
    $aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"] = $_POST['sepabanktransfer_swift'];
```

Answer (score 0):

($aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"] == '') **||** ($aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"]

$a || $b    Or  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.

($aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"]   **!=** $_POST['sepabanktransfer_swift'])

! $a    Not TRUE if $a is not TRUE.

[More about logical operators in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `$aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"]` is empty, or the `POST` input `ebt_swift` is different from its current value, it replaces the value with the `POST` input.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that if the `$aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"]` variable is empty but set **OR** the same `$aEbtVarSet["ebt_swift"]` variable is different than the `$_POST['sepabanktransfer_swift']` which is most likely set by a user with an `<input>` tag, then it will set the first variable to match the one sent by the user (replace/overwrite its previous value).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And ow can I rewrite this one to have something that is comparable with LIKE and not with different?

Comment: You can do that with the `strpos()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php. You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words useful. You just have to play along with it...